# Understanding source code management and documentation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, module, documentation

I have come across some large Javascript-based projects on Github that appear to be built from lots of individual Javascript files, but distributed as a single script.  I've also noticed that some of these seem to have special markup in the source code that automatically generates documentation.  Here's an example from the [source](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/vector/CircleMarker.js) for Leaflet's `CircleMarker` class:

```
import {Path} from './Path';
import * as Util from '../../core/Util';
import {toLatLng} from '../../geo/LatLng';
import {Bounds} from '../../geometry/Bounds';

/*
 * @class CircleMarker
 * @aka L.CircleMarker
 * @inherits Path
 *
 * A circle of a fixed size with radius specified in pixels. Extends `Path`.
 */

export var CircleMarker = Path.extend({

// @section
// @aka CircleMarker options
options: {
    fill: true,

    // @option radius: Number = 10
    // Radius of the circle marker, in pixels
    radius: 10
},
```

I think I understand the role of the `import` and `export` statements at runtime, but do these statements have a role in assembling the source files into the composite script?  If so, is it standardised, or specific to some tool?  Similarly, are the `@markup` comments a standard format? Where might this all be described?  To me, it isn't obvious from just looking at the source code in the repo.

To clarify, I am looking for answers that would help me research how to apply this type of modularity and self-documentation in my own projects.  I am not looking for recommendations for particular tools, or that are specifically about Leaflet, although if the example above is tool-specific, that would be good to know.  Rather, I'm more interesting in finding out the standard or best practice way of doing this.

Comment: [RTM](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) for a start

Comment: The CONTRIBUTING file for Leaflet tells me what they use on that project, but it doesn't tell me whether they are using a standard or tool-specific approach.

Comment: They use NODE,  PhantomJS,  Jekyll, Leafdoc which is NaturalDocs- and JSdoc-like documentation generator. If you want to know more, why not ask them?